# copy paste of www folder from one to another project is not working properly

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app

I have one ready-made project and I want to use basic functionality of ready-made project into another project. So, I have pasted www folder into another project but giving some popup errors.

Project Root Folder -> platform -> android -> app -> src -> main -> assets -> www

copy this www folder into new project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-use **www** folder from one project to another project but make sure

www -> cordova.js
    -> cordova_plugins.js

these two files cordova.js and cordova_plugin.js should not be replaced in another project.
Rest all the files can be re-used but not these two because of sometimes may have version difference.

In your case, you can copy all the files from www folder to another project without cordova.js and cordova_plugin.js. It will resolve pop issue.